# Many submatrices with permanent zero

Tags: linear-algebra, permanent

Suppose $A$ is an $8 \times 8$ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_5$  with the properties that:

- $per(A)=0$.

  The permanent of every $6 \times 6$ and $7 \times 7$ submatrix is zero.

My question is: from here, **what must be true about $A$**?

For example, one implication is that the polynomial $per(xI-A)$ has $0$ as a root with multiplicity at least $3$. 
However, outside of this, nothing else (to me) seems clearly true about $A$. Can I, for instance, say anything about the invertibility of $A$?

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect it to tell you anything about invertibility? Unless the characteristic is $2$ the permanent generally tells you nothing about that.

Comment: @MattSamuel No, in fact I suspect it wont. However, with so many vanishes subpermanents, I suspect/hope there is _some_ implication.